# HTTPCACHE not working when deploying scrapy project to scrapyd

Tags: python, middleware, scrapy, http-caching, scrapyd

When I try to use HTTPCACHE with scrapyd I get the following error:

`[scrapy] WARNING: Disabled Httpcache Middlware: unable to find scrapy.cfg file to infer project data dir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that http caching defaults to using the relative path `httpcache`.

This works when you run the spider normally from the command line, but not when running it as a service.

The solution is to set the [`HTTPCACHE_DIR`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-dir) setting to an absolute path.

Comment: ie: absolute path on the server... so yes, even though the spider is a client that is deployed to a server, the client tells the scrapyd service where on the server's filesystem to put the cache. The dir must be writable by the scrapyd process.

Comment: Still a relavant answer, but the link to the docs is now [this one](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-dir).